# Plot the datapoints in a plot_model function

Tags: r, plot, geom-point

I'm trying to add the datapoints using geom_point() to the plot_model() that is showing the linear relationship between the age and left.LGN variables.

```
plot <- plot_model(m1, terms = c("age"), type = "pred") +
    geom_point(data = data, aes(x = age, y = Left.LGN)) +
    labs(x = "Age (standardized)", y = "Adj. Left-LGN (standardized volume)", size = 20)
```

The script works until I add the third variable ("sex"):

```
plot <- plot_model(m1, terms = c("age", "sex"), type = "pred") +
   geom_point(data = data, aes(x = age, y = Left.LGN, color = sex, group = sex)) +
   labs(x = "Age (standardized)", y = "Adj. Left-LGN (standardized volume)", size = 20)
```

in which I got this error:

```
Error in `geom_point()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'group_col' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Has anybody had the same issue?

I expect to have a plot showing the relationship between age and Left-LGN volume related to males and females, adding the datapoints from the data.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have your data or model, but we can reproduce your problem with the following set-up:

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

data <- data.frame(age = rep(31:70, 2),
                   Left.LGN = c(31:70, 41:80)/6 + 100 + rnorm(80),
                   sex = rep(c('Male', 'Female'), each = 40))

m1 <- lm(Left.LGN ~ age + sex, data)
```

Now there is no problem using your own plotting code to generate a plot with just `age`:

```r
plot_model(m1, terms = c("age"), type = "pred") +
  geom_point(data = data, aes(x = age, y = Left.LGN)) +
  labs(x = "Age (standardized)", 
       y = "Adj. Left-LGN (standardized volume)", 
       size = 20)
```

[image]

But if we try to add in the `sex` variable, we get the same error that you report:

```r
plot_model(m1, terms = c("age", "sex"), type = "pred") +
  geom_point(data = data, 
             aes(x = age, y = Left.LGN, color = sex, group = sex)) +
  labs(x = "Age (standardized)", 
       y = "Adj. Left-LGN (standardized volume)", 
       size = 20)
#> Error in `geom_point()`:
#> ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
#> i Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
#> Caused by error in `FUN()`:
#> ! object 'group_col' not found
```

The reason for the error is that `plot_model` generates a `ggplot` object, which has aesthetic mappings to variables present in the data frame that `plot_model` creates from your model. One of these variables is called `group_col`, which of course is not present in your own data frame. To fix this, simply specify `inherit.aes = FALSE` in your `geom_point` layer:

```r
plot_model(m1, terms = c("age", "sex"), type = "pred") +
  geom_point(data = data, 
             aes(x = age, y = Left.LGN, color = sex, group = sex),
             inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "Age (standardized)", 
       y = "Adj. Left-LGN (standardized volume)", 
       size = 20)
```

[image]

Note though that `plot_model` also includes the parameter `show.data` if you want to include the data points in your model, so instead of adding a `geom_point` layer, you can do:

```r
plot_model(m1, terms = c("age", "sex"), type = "pred", show.data = TRUE) +
  labs(x = "Age (standardized)", 
       y = "Adj. Left-LGN (standardized volume)", 
       size = 20)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>